# Parse command lines from the following string in C#?

Tags: c#

I have strings in the format of:

```
httP;//whatvere[CanIncludeSpaces"].url -a -b -c
```

How do I get the arguments -a, -b, -c in a string array?

Thanks

Comment: are those strings supposed to represent actual hyperlinks, or is it jut a coincidence that the example you posted seems to resemble a hyperlink?

Comment: No the first part is a url, the arguments are regular args

Comment: The can include spaces part is delimited by []?

Comment: You could use regex to get it...

Comment: hyphens are expected to be found in the URLs also?

Comment: you can just reverse the string, split it on white spaces, loop through the strings and stop when you run into the first one that doesnt start with a dash(-) as each arg will (per your exmple) have the dash in front of it and they will all be at the end.

Comment: yea..that is a good way to do it i guess.

Comment: Does it actually have `.url` at the end?

Comment: Ok, then it looks like that can be used to be the delimiter between the URL and args, and my solution should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
var str = "httP;//whatvere[CanIncludeSpaces\"].url -a -b -c";
var endOfUrl = str.LastIndexOf(".url") + 4;
var args = str.Substring(endOfUrl).Split(new[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
//args is ["-a", "-b", "-c"]
//also, the URL is easy to get:
var url = str.Substring(0, endOfUrl);
//url is now 'httP;//whatvere[CanIncludeSpaces"].url'
```